# getServerSideProps is not updating data with import

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm having a problem with `getServerSideProps` in NextJS not updating values on page load. It seems to be having the same effect as using `getStaticProps` when calling from data that is an imported JSON file.

Here's the applicable code:

`/update/[...id].js`

```
import { hasPermission, getPermissions } from '../../lib/permissions'
...
//in the page function I use the ternary to check permission of the user
{ (hasPermission(session.user.email, `${params.id[0]}-edit`, permissions)) ? <HasPerm /> : <NoPerm /> }
...
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const params = context.query
  const permissions = getPermissions()
  return {
    props: { params, permissions }
  }
}
```

`/lib/permissions.js`

```
import permissions from '../db/users.json'

export function hasPermission(username, group, perm = false) {
  if (!perm)
    perm = permissions

  if (username in perm && perm[username].groups.includes(group)) {
    return true
  }
  if (perm.all.groups.includes(group)) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

export function getPermissions() {
  return permissions
}
```

For SSR pages that were understandably doing this to begin with, I pass in the permissions to the page in `getStaticProps` and pass those values into my `hasPermission()` function in those pages so that they are revalidated on permissions change. Yet there is no revalidation option in `getServerSideProps` so the data is not revalidated at all. I was using `getInitialProps` before but pretty much everyone discourages that because it disables ASO.

How do I use `getServerSideProps` such that my imported json is at least revalidated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using the json import and used `fs` instead for other reasons but the issue is resolved by using dynamic imports in the `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const permissions = await import('../db/users.json')
}
```

Also don't make my same mistake of passing the whole permissions database to every user as was being done by using a function like `getPermissions` in `getStaticProps` to get the data to the `hasPermission` function in the page. Instead, only serve data with `getServerSideProps` if the user has permission. In other words, ensure you're holding the data back from the server-side. Then you can also pass through an individual's permissions to the page if you need to, like for displaying a message saying you don't have permission.